# Why does charAt work differently depending on the data type it is printed as

Tags: java, char, primitive, charat

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String a = "(4 + 4i)";
        String b = "(2 + 3i)";
        int g = 1;
        int c = a.charAt( g ); // sets c to 52
        System.out.println( c ); // prints 52
        System.out.println( (double) a.charAt( g ) ); // prints 52.0
        System.out.println( a.charAt( g ) ); // prints 4
        System.out.println( 2 * a.charAt( g ) ); // prints 104
    }
}
```

I was trying to write code to multiply imaginary numbers which is why I have "i" in the strings. So I thought take first and and convert to int or double. This gave me 52 which baffled me. However when I printed directly to console, it worked but only without the double. This is useless because I need to use it elsewhere. So what is going on here? Would it better to try to parse parts of strings a and to int or double and are there alternatives to manipulating numbers within strings without using parse? And are there methods that can deal with imaginary numbers i.e. "e^pi * i = 1"?

Comment: Well... the short answer is: If you deal with `char`s, you deal with [ASCII-Codes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) and the character `'4'` has ASCII-Code `52`. If you transform a `char` into an `int` (which you do by `int c = a.charAt(...)`, you get the ASCII-code, although the ASCII Code represents a digit. IF you, however, print the `char` directly (`System.out.println(a.charAt(...))`, Java is smart enough to translate the ASCII-Code in the actual character. (Remark: the ASCII-part is actually a lie, Java Characters are UTF-16)

Comment: 52 is the charcode of the character '4'

Comment: For complex number, you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997053/does-java-have-a-class-for-complex-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String is a sequence of symbols, such as letters, punctuation, and digits, called characters. Each character is associated with a number. One common way to do this is with what is called the ASCII characters. In this case, you see that the character `'4'` is represented by the number `52`.

With this in mind, let's look at some of your code:

```
int c = a.charAt( g );
```

This line silently converts the character to its numerical value. By "numerical value" I mean the number that represents the character, not the value of the digit itself. In this case, the character `'4'` has the numerical value `52`.

```
System.out.println( a.charAt( g ) ); // prints 4
```

This prints out the **character** `'4'`, not the `int` `4`. It is extremely important that you learn the difference between the digit characters and their integer values.

In order to get the number `4` so that you can perform arithmetic operations, you must parse the `String`. The function `Integer.valueOf()` will help a lot with this.

You should also learn about classes and objects. For example, you can create a `Complex` class which will allow you to use complex numbers as a single entity with its own operations.

To get the numerical values that you want, you need to use `Integer.valueOf()` or `Double.valueOf()` depending on whether you want an `int` or a `double`:

```
int c = Integer.valueOf(a.charAt(g))
```

You will need to use more sophisticated parsing methods if you want to allow numbers with multiple digits or decimal points.

Comment: While the answer is absolutely correct, I think a major point of confusion for OP is Java's casting-behaviour, especially when implicitly casting from `char` to `int`. Maybe you want to discuss this topic more verbosely in your answer?

Comment: @chrylis Yeah, but do you want to confuse OP more than s*he is already? For the sake of explanation, ASCII is sufficient :)

Comment: @chrylis For the purposes of this question, the exact character set is not terribly important. The **existence** of such a thing as a character set is the primary issue.

Answer (score 0):

You get 52 because the ascii value of `'4'` is 52.

```
System.out.println("(4 + 4i)".charAt(1) == '4'); // '4' == '4'
System.out.println((int) '4'); // <-- 52
```

If you want to convert a `char` to its' `int` value, you need to check that it is in the expected range and then parse it. You can subtract `'0'` from the value, or use `Character.digit` - like

```
char c = '4';
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    System.out.println((int) (c - '0'));
    System.out.println(Character.digit(c, 10));
}
```

And, finally, [`System#out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), that is what provides the overloaded methods to write `int` (or `char`, or `String`, or `double`, etc).