# Is there a way to return a Double AND a String from a single method in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have a method which calculates the square root of only negative numbers

(which is `sqrt(x)=sqrt(-x) +"*i"` , where x is a `double` and `"*i"` is a string)

the problem I have is that this method returns a double and a string which are two different variable types, so the question is how do I make this method return both?:

```
public static **(what goes here?)** myFunction(double x){

    return(sqrt(x)+"*i");

}
```

this code is wrong but I do not know how to fix it, any tips?

Comment: You can write a class that contains a string and an int, and return an instance of that. Not clear from your question why you need to return a string and an int from this particular method. If you want to return `sqrt(x)+"*i"`, that's just a string.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997053/does-java-have-a-class-for-complex-numbers

Comment: khelwood I think I might, ernest_k, it would be helpful if I knew what it meant, i'm still knew to this. luk2303 not a duplicate, I don't know what an object is (yet, my teacher said we will learn about it in about 8 months).

Comment: You not knowing what an object is does not matter to us. We will not explain the basic concepts of OOP to you.

Comment: You don't need to return both: you just need to return a type that represents an imaginary number. The "*i" is purely presentation.

Comment: "we will learn about it in about 8 months" I would suggest there isn't 8 months of stuff to learn in Java without objects. They're fundamental.

Comment: @andyTurner haha I always work ahead (ex. why im asking this, my classroom is doing random numbers)

Comment: @andyTurner and what do you mean with the representation of an imaginary number?

Comment: @luk2302 isn't the purpose of asking questions to understand things you do not have knowledge of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't return multiple values from methods.

What you could do is to define a custom type which wraps your string and double values. Eg:

```
public class MyResult {
    private double res1;
    private String res2;

    public MyResult(double res1, String res2) {
        this.res1 = res1;
        this.res2 = res2;
    }
}
```

And use this in your method:

```
public static MyResult myFunction(double x){
    return new MyResult(sqrt(x),"*i");
}
```

Comment: how would I define such a variable type?

Comment: This isn't a good approach since `"*i"` is a constant...

Comment: @sandroHakimArrangements You could create a new file MyResult.java, or include it in the same file without `public` keyword.