# My Mandelbrot set doesn't generate. What's wrong with my equation?

Tags: java, swing, math, mandelbrot

```
//Generator class
public class Generator {
double jump;
double sizeModifier;
int iterationRate,range;
ComplexNumber c;
public Generator(double jump) {
    this.jump=jump;
    this.sizeModifier=40;
    this.iterationRate=10;
    this.range=100;
    c=new ComplexNumber();
}
    public void generateSet(){
        DrawSet ds = new DrawSet();
        int ticker=0;
        for(double i=-2*range;i<=range;i+=jump){
            for(double j=-2*range;j<=range;j+=jump){
                c= new ComplexNumber((i/range),(j/range));
                double fz=c.square().mod()+c.mod();
                //System.out.println("c mod is: "+c.mod());
                //System.out.println("fz is: "+fz);
                if (fz < 2) {
                    for(int k=0;k<=iterationRate;k++) {
                        //System.out.println("nc:"+nc);
                        ticker++;
                        //System.out.println("ticker:"+ticker);
                        if(ticker==iterationRate) {
                            ds.addPoint(i + 450, j + 450);

                    }
                    if(fz>=2){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        fz = Math.pow(fz, 2) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            ticker=0;
        }
    }
}
//Drawset class
public class DrawSet extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<Point> Points;
private ArrayList<Point> nPoints;


GraphicWindow gw;
public DrawSet(){
    this.Points=new ArrayList<>();
    this.nPoints=new ArrayList<>();
    gw = new GraphicWindow(1000,1000);
    gw.add(this);

}
public void addPoint(double x,double y){
    int ix=(int)x;
    int iy=(int)y;
    //int iwidth=(int)width*sizeModifier;
    //int iheight=(int)height*sizeModifier;
    Point a=new Point(ix,iy);
    Points.add(a);
    //System.out.println(Points.size());
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int pointSize = 1;
        super.paintComponents(g);
        System.out.println(Points.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval((int) Points.get(i).getX(), (int) Points.get(i).getY(), pointSize, pointSize);
        }
    }
```

The basic problem is that fz is never <2 after just 10 iterations, so no points are drawn. Why is this? What equation should I be implementing?

I am using a complex number to generate the value. The class which I use can be seen here:
https://github.com/abdulfatir/jcomplexnumber/
(or on the stack overflow forum [Does Java have a class for complex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997053/does-java-have-a-class-for-complex-numbers) by Mr Abdul Fatir)

Comment: Observationally, `Generator` should not be creating a new instance of `DrawSet` and `DrawSet` should not be creating a new instance of `GraphicWindow`, this is causing side effects in your code.  A better solution would be to have the `Generator` return the data set to a caller for them to then apply as they saw fit - your code is to tightly coupled and generates a bunch of unexpected side effects

Answer (score 0):

Okay, observationally

- `Generator` should not be creating a new instance of `DrawSet`
- `DrawSet` should not be creating a new instance of `GraphicWindow`

These are the responsibilities of these classes or methods.  This is highly coupling your code and generating side effects.

Instead, `generate` should pass back the points it creates and these should then be applied in what ever way you want, `Generator` shouldn't care.

Because I don't have access to your full code, I've just hacked together a random series of points instead to illustrate the point.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DrawSet drawSet = new DrawSet();
                Generator generator = new Generator(100);
                drawSet.setPoints(generator.generateSet());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(drawSet);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawSet extends JPanel {

        private ArrayList<Point> points;
        private ArrayList<Point> nPoints;

        public DrawSet() {
            this.points = new ArrayList<>();
            this.nPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        public void setPoints(ArrayList<Point> points) {
            this.points = points;
            repaint();
        }

//        public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
//            int ix = (int) x;
//            int iy = (int) y;
//            //int iwidth=(int)width*sizeModifier;
//            //int iheight=(int)height*sizeModifier;
//            Point a = new Point(ix, iy);
//            Points.add(a);
//            //System.out.println(Points.size());
//        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int pointSize = 5;
            super.paintComponents(g);
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawOval((int) points.get(i).getX(), (int) points.get(i).getY(), pointSize, pointSize);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Generator {

        double jump;
        double sizeModifier;
        int iterationRate, range;
        //ComplexNumber c;

        public Generator(double jump) {
            this.jump = jump;
            this.sizeModifier = 40;
            this.iterationRate = 10;
            this.range = 100;
            //c = new ComplexNumber();
        }

        public ArrayList<Point> generateSet() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(range);
            for (int index = 0; index < range; index++) {
                int x = (int)(490 * rnd.nextDouble());
                int  y = (int)(490 * rnd.nextDouble());
                points.add(new Point(x, y));
            }
            return points;

//            DrawSet ds = new DrawSet();
//            int ticker = 0;
//            for (double i = -2 * range; i <= range; i += jump) {
//                for (double j = -2 * range; j <= range; j += jump) {
//                    c = new ComplexNumber((i / range), (j / range));
//                    double fz = c.square().mod() + c.mod();
//                    //System.out.println("c mod is: "+c.mod());
//                    //System.out.println("fz is: "+fz);
//                    if (fz < 2) {
//                        for (int k = 0; k <= iterationRate; k++) {
//                            //System.out.println("nc:"+nc);
//                            ticker++;
//                            //System.out.println("ticker:"+ticker);
//                            if (ticker == iterationRate) {
//                                ds.addPoint(i + 450, j + 450);
//
//                            }
//                            if (fz >= 2) {
//                                break;
//                            } else {
//                                fz = Math.pow(fz, 2) + 1;
//                            }
//                        }
//                    }
//                    ticker = 0;
//                }
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also made the `pointSize` bigger, so you can actually see the results, although I'd consider filling the points.

If the `Generator` is takes a long time to perform its calculations, you might consider using a `SwingWorker` to perform the operation.  This will allow to offload the operation to seperate thread and not block the main UI thread.  You can then use the `SwingWorker` to either feed back each individual point as it's calculated or all the points when the whole generation is done, back to the main UI thread in a safe manner.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

> Why is this?

Swing is lazy.  It won't make repaints or updates to the UI unless it thinks it needs to.  So, if you change some state the UI is depending on, you need to nudge Swing to encourage it to make a new paint pass.  In the simplest terms, this means calling `repaint` on the component which is has changed

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however there is output for my program when I remove the    if(fz>=2){
                            break;
                        } from my generateSet method. In this case it outputs a circle with which is correct as it's the loci of all points less than 2 away. My problem is that fz never seems to remain in the bounds of 2. Would you like to see my full code? It isn't that much more