# How to solve imaginary quadratic roots in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying a lot but it only shows NaN. I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

```
 class Imaginary{
    
     double a = 2;
     double b = 3;
     double c = 5;
     double result = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    
     if(result < 0.0){
      double im1 = -2 + (Math.sqrt((result))/ 10);
      double im2 = -2 - (Math.sqrt((result))/ 10);
    
    
      System.out.println("x = " + imaginary1 + " or x = " + imaginary2);
            }
 }
```

Comment: From the docs for `Math.sqrt`: Return Value:
This method returns the positive square root of a. If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN.

Comment: [Does Java have a class for complex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997053/does-java-have-a-class-for-complex-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take negate `result` to make it positive before taking the square root (taking square roots of negative numbers always results in NaN) and append "i" before printing.

```
double real = -b / (2*a);
double img = Math.sqrt(-result) / (2*a);
System.out.println("x = " + real + " + " + img +"i or x = " + real + " - " + img + "i");
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use sqrt(result) since it will always result in you taking the square root of a negative number (that is your condition for result). Instead try to use a formula (eg completing the square).

Hope it answers your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a complex root, you need to work with complex numbers to solve the equation. Java lacks builtin support for complex numbers, but you can e.g. use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html#sqrt()):

```
if (result < 0.0) {
    final Complex cb = new Complex(-b, 0.0);
    final Complex root = new Complex(result, 0.0).sqrt();
    final Complex r1 = cb.add(root).divide(2 * a);
    final Complex r2 = cb.subtract(root).divide(2 * a);
}
```